# how to set search box,sorting and pagination in angular7 using datatables

Tags: angular, datatable, angular7

hello there i am trying to get the pagination and search filter in angular7 but i am not getting pagination and search filter am getting the sorting functionality.and also help me to get the search filter code. can you please help me out this problem

here is testm.component.html

```
   <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
            <ng-container matColumnDef="{{column.id}}" *ngFor="let column of columnNames">
              <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> {{column.value}} </mat-header-cell>
              <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element[column.id]}} </mat-cell>
            </ng-container>

            <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
            <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;">  </mat-row>
           </mat-table>
        <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
```

and testm.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import {MatPaginator, MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material';
import { MatTableDataSource, MatSort } from '@angular/material';
    import { DataSource } from '@angular/cdk/table';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-testm',
  templateUrl: './testm.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./testm.component.scss']
})
export class TestmComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }
  dataSource;
  displayedColumns = [];
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;


  /**
   * Pre-defined columns list for user table
   */
  columnNames = [{
    id: "position",
    value: "No."

  }, {
    id: "name",
    value: "Name"
  },
  {
    id: "weight",
    value: "Weight"
  },
  {
    id: "symbol",
    value: "Symbol"
  }];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.displayedColumns = this.columnNames.map(x => x.id);
        this.createTable();
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  }
  createTable() {
    let tableArr: Element[] = [
    { position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 12, symbol: 'H' },
    { position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 32, symbol: 'He' },
    { position: 3, name: 'Lithium', weight: 35, symbol: 'Li' },
    { position: 4, name: 'Beryllium', weight: 65, symbol: 'Be' },
    { position: 5, name: 'Boron', weight: 98, symbol: 'B' },
    { position: 6, name: 'Carbon', weight: 49, symbol: 'C' }
    ];
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(tableArr);
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }

}
export interface Element {
  position: number,
  name: string,
  weight: number,
  symbol: string
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For sorting and paginating, you have to import the "AfterViewInit" interface from @angular/core.

Then you will able to call the ngAfterViewInit() method. e.g.,

```
ngAfterViewInit() {

this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;}
```

For filtering, use the following code on top of the Mat Table. e.g.,

```html
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput type="text" (keyup)="doFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Filter">
  </mat-form-field>
```

And implement the doFilter() inside the component.

```js
doFilter(filterValue: string) {
    console.log(filterValue);
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLocaleLowerCase();
  }
```